# How to get some data into Google spreadsheet?

Tags: charts, html, spreadsheet

I have a webpage

https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=RELIANCE&x=NSE&i=60&p=5d&f=d,c,o,h,l&df=cpct&auto=1&ts=1266701290218

And I'm trying to get the data into a chart.

Any suggestions on how this can be done? Please no code, I just can't get any of it work.

Answer (score 0):

you could use python in this way (writing csv files that are well understood by excel or similar):

```
#!/bin/python
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=RELIANCE&x=NSE&i=60&p=5d&f=d,c,o,h,l&df=cpct&auto=1&ts=1266701290218')
data = response.read()
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
            quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for line in data.split("\n"):
        writer.writerow(list(line.split(",")))
```

be sure to open it setting the comma as field delimiter.

sorry I skipped the no-code part.

Comment: I kinda thought that code would be involved. Will lead to the question "What do I do with it now?"

Comment: if you are brave enough you could search how to install python on your platform, create a file named getdata.py and put my code in that file, execute it with python (if you trust the source!) and you will have a file named data.csv in the same directory that you could import in any (or maybe many of them) spreadsheet application.  NOTE if you are on windows you probably should remove the first line (#!/bin/python)